# Query result will into an int or a string

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database, connection

```
string komut = "SELECT Count FROM servers WHERE id = 1";
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(komut, baglanti);
int result = da;
```

My codes like this I want that : "SELECT Count FROM Server WHERE id = 1" query's result will transfer into result varuable.
How can i do that ? Thank you.

Comment: Have you read anything about *MySqlDataAdapter*, before asking it here? I don't think you are the first one who tries to get a value from a DB

Comment: Uh,I know it sends query

Answer (score 0):

To properly accomplish such a goal:

```
var query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Rows FROM [Table] WHERE Id = @Id";
```

You would do that to prevent *Syntax Query Language (SQL)* Injection.  Once you have your query defined, you would:

```
private readonly string dbConnection;
private const string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Rows FROM [Table] WHERE Id = @Id";

int? rows;
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(dbConnection))
     using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
     {
          connection.Open();
          command.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
          // command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id); // Another approach.
          using(SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
               if(reader.Read())
                    rows = reader["Rows"] as int?;
     }
```

That should return an `integer` of the valid row count.

**Important:** The `int?` will allow a `null` to be returned if the cast to an integer fails.  Rather then throw an *Invalid Cast Exception*.  Secondly, a bulk of the data is wrapped in a `using` which will implement the `IDisposable` method to free up resources.

The rest should be relatively straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

sql query is not valid.

count function need a param like count(*)